# How to parse jsonstring in iOS using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have the following json,

```
{   
    "method":"login", 
    "data":{  
        "username":"abc", 
        "password":"123" 
    } 
}
```

I'm using following code to parse it,

```
NSString* loginMethod= json[@"method"];
NSString* credentials= json[@"data"];
NSLog(@"credentials %@",credentials);
```

I'm able to get the value for the key data but I'm not be able to get the value of username and password. How to get those values?

Comment: is json is string or response any API call

Comment: im just loading a local json file

Comment: check my answer below for string

Comment: yeah that works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if json is in respose data then

```
NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:request.responseData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
```

if json is in string then

```
NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; options:kNilOptions error:&err];


NSString* loginMethod= [jsonDic objectForKey:@"method"];

NSString* usename= [[jsonDic objectForKey:@"data"]objectForKey:@"username"];
NSString* password= [[jsonDic objectForKey:@"data"]objectForKey:@"password"];
```

Answer (score 2):

change

```
NSString* credentials= json[@"data"];
```

to

```
NSDictionary* credentials= json[@"data"];
```

then

```
NSString *username = credentials[@"username"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get those values by `credentials[@"username"]` and `credentials[@"password"]`.

Answer (score 0):

do like

reason it deverives like nested `Dictionry`

```
NSString* loginMethod= json[@"method"]; // this is correct

NSString* username= json[@"data"][@"username"];
NSString* password= json[@"data"][@"password"];
```

**Choice -2**

```
 NSString* loginMethod= json[@"method"]; 

// This isNested Dictionary so Do like
NSDictionary* temp= json[@"data"];
NSString *username = temp[@"username"];
NSString * password = temp[@"password"];
```